# Calculate Percentage Of Certified Managers

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I asked a similar question a few weeks ago, but now the requirements have changed.

Considering the following tables:
http://www.maroisconsulting.com/Temp/query.png

I need to create a query that returns the percentages of employees who are managers (Titles.IsManager) and who have a date in the Certified field (Employees.Certified). The results need to be grouped by the Group each store is in.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT d.GroupId, 
       Sum(d.cert_complete) AS SumOfcert_complete, 
       Count(d.cert_complete) AS CountOfcert_complete
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
        s.GroupId,
        e.EmployeeID,
        IIf(e.Certified Is Null,0,1) AS cert_complete
    FROM
        ((Stores AS s
        INNER JOIN EmployeeStores AS es ON s.StoreId = es.StoreId)
        INNER JOIN Employees AS e ON es.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeID)
        INNER JOIN Titles AS t ON e.TitleId = t.TitleId
    )  AS d
WHERE t.IsManager
GROUP BY d.GroupId;
```

And then this

```
SELECT q.GroupId, 
      (SumOfcert_complete/CountOfcert_complete)*100 AS percent_certified, 
      Groups.GroupName
FROM qryGroupCert_base AS q 
INNER JOIN Groups ON q.GroupId = Groups.GroupId;
```

You can see in the first query where I added the Titles table.

1) I get prompted for the IsManager, although I don't know why
2) The results coming back are not different than before I added the IsManager

Anyone see what's wrong here?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your first query, you have this subquery which includes Titles aliased as "t":

```
(SELECT DISTINCT
    s.GroupId,
    e.EmployeeID,
    IIf(e.Certified Is Null,0,1) AS cert_complete
FROM
    ((Stores AS s
    INNER JOIN EmployeeStores AS es ON s.StoreId = es.StoreId)
    INNER JOIN Employees AS e ON es.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeID)
    INNER JOIN Titles AS t ON e.TitleId = t.TitleId
)  AS d
```

Then, *after* the definition of the subquery, you have this WHERE clause:

```
WHERE t.IsManager
```

The problem is the "t" alias and IsManager column only exist within the the subquery --> they are unknown to the outer (parent) query.  In cases where the Access database engine encounters something it doesn't recognize as an object name, function, literal value, or SQL keyword, it thinks that something must be a parameter ... so pops up the input box asking you to provide a value for the (IsManager) parameter.

I think you should move the WHERE clause inside the subquery definition.

```
SELECT d.GroupId, 
       Sum(d.cert_complete) AS SumOfcert_complete, 
       Count(d.cert_complete) AS CountOfcert_complete
FROM [SELECT DISTINCT
        s.GroupId,
        e.EmployeeID,
        IIf(e.Certified Is Null,0,1) AS cert_complete
    FROM
        ((Stores AS s
        INNER JOIN EmployeeStores AS es ON s.StoreId = es.StoreId)
        INNER JOIN Employees AS e ON es.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeID)
        INNER JOIN Titles AS t ON e.TitleId = t.TitleId
        WHERE t.IsManager = True
    ]. AS d
GROUP BY d.GroupId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to supply a criteria for t.IsManager, such as t.IsManager = TRUE. If the where clause doesn't have a value to set it equal to, Access probably isn't resolving it to the actual column, but thinks it's a query parameter.

Comment: The WHERE clause is for a bool field, so "WHERE IsManager" is the same as "WHERE IsManager = 1". The problem is that even with the Titles table added in and the the WHERE clause added on, the results are not changed from before. So I don't think the query is respecting the Titles join, but I don't know why

Comment: Don't you mean `WHERE IsManager = -1`? The value for Boolean TRUE in Access/Jet/ACE/VBA is -1, not 1. That said, while Access/Jet/ACE will understand your test of a Boolean WHERE (I didn't know that until I tested in response to this question), I still think you should explicitly specify the comparison value, i.e., `WHERE IsManager = True`. It's just much easier to understand and read. The fascinating thing to me is that the Access QBE grid's Design View represents `WHERE IsManager` in the grid's Criteria row as `<>False`.